# Python GitLab - Getting artifacts result in list error

Tags: python, gitlab

I try to download build artifacts from a CI/CD pipeline by using the GitLab API for Python. I took a look at the [documentation](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/pipelines_and_jobs.html#jobs) and wrote the following example:

```
import os
import time
import gitlab
import subprocess

gl = gitlab.Gitlab("MyRepo.de", private_token = "A Token")
project = gl.projects.get("MyProject")
pipelines = project.pipelines.list()

# Get the latest job from the latest pipeline
CurrentJob = None
for Pipeline in project.pipelines.list():
    if(Pipeline.status == "success"):
        for Job in Pipeline.jobs.list():
            if(Job.status == "success"):
                CurrentJob = Job

        break

zipfn = "___artifacts.zip"
with open(zipfn, "wb") as f:
    CurrentJob.artifacts(streamed=True, action=f.write)
subprocess.run(["unzip", "-bo", zipfn])
os.unlink(zipfn)
```

But the program exit with the error `'list' object is not callable` in the line `CurrentJob.artifacts(streamed=True, action=f.write)` and the debugger shows three different files:

[image]

But the example uses the same lines of code. What is the correct way to access and download the files? I don´t find any solution in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distinction here is subtle. Using `pipeline.jobs.list` doesn't use the same underlying API as `project.jobs.list` (or `.get`)

In terms of the Python-Gitlab library, when you do `pipeline.jobs.list()` you get a list of `gitlab.v4.objects.ProjectPipelineJob` objects. The `.artifacts` attribute of this type of object is not a method -- it's an a list containing information about the artifacts, like file type, size file name, etc -- which is what you're seeing in your image.

This is different from a `gitlab.v4.objects.ProjectJob` object, which is what is shown in the documentation. You obtain this kind of object from `project.jobs.get` or `project.jobs.list`.

So, to correct this error you can edit the tail end of your code as follows:

```py
job_id = CurrentJob.id
CurrentJob = project.jobs.get(job_id)

zipfn = "___artifacts.zip"
with open(zipfn, "wb") as f:
    CurrentJob.artifacts(streamed=True, action=f.write)
subprocess.run(["unzip", "-bo", zipfn])
os.unlink(zipfn)
```